# CORS not set when sending GET request

Tags: php, browser, cors, http-headers

I am creating an API and I want every single website to be able to send a GET request to `/log.php?a=`. The value after the a is logged to a text file. But I get:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com/log.php/?a=dW5kZWZpbmVk. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

This is the log.php file:

```php
<?php

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
$myfile = fopen("test.txt", "w");
fwrite($myfile, $_GET['a']);

?>
```

Comment: Setting the Access-Control-Allow-Methods to * does not work either

Comment: Looks like the URL in the question is a bit different from the URL in the error message (in the error message there's an extra `/` after `log.php`. Can you remove it and see what happens?

Comment: @Niros well this worked. Thanks. Can you add this as an answer, so I can accept it and close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the URL in the question is a bit different from the URL in the error message (in the error message there's an extra `/` after `log.php`)

Can you remove it and see what happens?